# getting System.ServiceModel.AddressAccessDeniedException on Vista for WCF service

Tags: wcf

We have an application that starts a WCF server and the app reads from it.

It starts and can be read fine on all Windows XP machines.

On our Vista machine, however, we get:

```
System.ServiceModel.AddressAccessDeniedException
"The process has no rights to this namespace."
System.Net.HttpListenerException
```

The URL is at localhost:

http://localhost:8731/ABC.Testing.Business.Core/SecurityService/?wsdl

The error message sent us here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733768.aspx

And we did what it said:

```
netsh http add urlacl url=... user=...
```

which changed the rights but the WCF service still cannot start on Vista.

Does anyone have any experience with this that could move us forward? Thanks.

Comment: I've had similar problems on Vista, which I haven't figured out yet. What error is it throwing now that you have run that netsh command? Have you tried giving that user local administrator privileges?

Comment: In the netsh command I gave the rights to the user than runs the application, but what I think I need to do is find out which process needs the rights, but this is a Unity-based app and the WCF is started before it even gets to the bootstrapper, so which process do I need to give rights to?

Comment: I think I'm in the same boat as you now...  not sure what to do :)
I've done the same thing with my service (netsh command), and it still won't run in Vista, but it runs fine in XP if I run the equivalent httpcfg command.  There must be some cryptic setting somewhere in Vista that is block us.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

try reading through this blog post and see if it helps.

http://blogs.msdn.com/paulwh/archive/2007/05/04/addressaccessdeniedexception-http-could-not-register-url-http-8080.aspx

Comment: "Page not found". Please add a quote and not only source link!

Answer (score 18):

I had a similar issue with Windows 7 running Visual Studio 2010. My solution was a simple WCF service library with a simple console project serving as the WCF service host.

My base address in app.config was "http://localhost:8080/BookService" and I forgot that I had to start Visual Studio as an administrator in order to get Windows to map that port to my app.

As soon as I started Visual Studio as an Administrator (right click, Run as administrator) it ran like a champ.

Answer (score -1):

I was having the similar problem while running the Project in VS2013 on Windows 8 OS, this problem get solved when I started my project as administrator..

Try to start up your app as administrator.

Thanks
Mayank Nagar